# moving data from sql server express 2008 to mssqlserver version 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know I'm going the wrong way but is there a way to move a database from a SQLEXPRESS 2008 server to an MSSQLServer version 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio on your SQL 2008 instance, right-click on the database whose data you want to move and choose Export Data... from the All Tasks submenu.  There are options to connect to many different data destinations.  For SQL 2000 your best bet is to connect to a Microsoft OLE Db for SQL Server destination and then plug your SQL 2000 server information in.

Do note, though, that SQL 2008 includes several new data types that are not available in previous versions of SQL Server.  If any of your tables use one of those data types the import will fail without doing a conversion.